# What are the meaning of curly brackets and %s and %f and %d in Drupal queries?

Tags: php, postgresql, drupal

I have to review a script from an web application (PHP based, built in Drupal 6, but I think this just a common script not specific to drupal 6, cmiiw). But I'm still learning about it.

Here is the code:

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {data} ( code, nominal, desc, proofnumber, uid) 
            VALUES ('%s', %f,'%s', '%s', %d)",  $code, $nominal, $desc, $proofnumber, $uid);
```

My questions:

1. What do the curly brackets mean?
2. What do `'%s'`, `%d`, and `%f` mean?
3. Why isn't it just written like this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO data (code, nominal, desc, proofnumber, uid) 
       VALUES ($code, $nominal, $desc, $proofnumber, $uid)`?
   ```

Comment: 1. It's a method Drupal uses to allow the global DB prefix to be prepended to table names 2. String, decimal and float respectively 3. Because [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection)

Comment: I'm downvoting this question since the other does not seems to have even read the db_query function documentation (which in the top 5 results when searching for "drupal dbquery" on any decent search engine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Curly brackets are for proper prefixing of table name, so `{data}` will become something like `myapp_data`, [see db_prefix_tables for more](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.inc/function/db_prefix_tables/6).
2. `%s`, `%d` and other ones are [sprintf format specifiers](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), you can find some examples in [db_query docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6).
3. All this is needed to implement querying in DB-agnostic way (#1), and to mitigate SQL-injections (#2).